# Inline tinymce shows error on toolbar click

Tags: angular, tinymce

My application needs to edit contents inline. Tinymce editor should appear inline on a button click.

Everything works fine, inline editor appears on button click and the content get highlighted for editing too. But while i start to edit, say to make a text bold the editor got disappeared and shows a console error like the one below;

> zone.js:199 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

```
at Object.read$1 [as read] (tinymce.js:15050)
at Object.createFromEditor (tinymce.js:15095)
at Object.add (tinymce.js:15266)
at Editor.addNonTypingUndoLevel (tinymce.js:15158)
at EventDispatcher.fire (tinymce.js:25978)
at Editor.fire (tinymce.js:26084)
at tinymce.js:11940
at tinymce.js:2206
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
```

The issue is only with the inline editor, the other one is working fine. But requirement is to use inline editor.

This is the function i call to show the inline tinymce:

```
openEditor(elementid: string) {
    let selector = '#' + elementid;
    let strcontent = $(selector).html();
    var plugins_str = 'paste,save,charmap,link,autoresize';
    var toolbar_icons = "bold | italic | link unlink";
    tinymce.baseURL = '../../../assets';

    tinymce.init({
        selector: selector,
        cache_suffix: "?v=4",
        entity_encoding: "raw",
        valid_elements: "*[*]",
        menubar: false,
        toolbar1: toolbar_icons,
        plugins: [ plugins_str ],
        statusbar: false,
        inline: true,
        resize: true,
        initialValue: {},
        autofocus: true,
        save_onsavecallback: function (e) {
            var savecontent = e.getContent();
        },
        save_oncancelcallback: function (e) {
            e.remove();
            var corresp_elm = document.getElementById(elementid);
            corresp_elm.outerHTML = that.editor_in_data;
            that.reinstateEditableElements();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you using Tiny's official Angular component?
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular